# How to add a new callback method without affecting other calls to the method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following method

```
DoSomething(param1, param2, onCloseCallback, param3, param4)
```

I would need to add another callback method to call at the end of DoSomenthing
without affecting other calls to the method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you mean "function" instead of "method", a "method" usually is tied to an object in OOP.

Comment: `DoSomething(param1, param2, onCloseCallback, param3, param4, anotherCallback)` ?

Comment: If your function parameters grow to half a dozen or so, you should really consider refactoring that into something more manageable.

Comment: What about `function DoSomething(param1, param2, onCloseCallback, param3, param4) { /* old code */ /* call the new code that you want to call at the end */ }`

Comment: Maybe you want to refactor this to use promises for easier chaining of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoSomething(param1, param2, onCloseCallback, param3, param4, anotherCallback) {
  //previous implementation here
  anotherCallback && anotherCallback()
}
```

This way existing calls to DoSomething are not affected by the change and new calls to DoSomething call anotherCallback at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just simply put another callback at the end of parameters, then call your callback at the bottom of the function:

```
function DoSomething(param1, param2, onCloseCallback, param3, param4, onEndCallback) {

  // ....

  if(onEndCallback) onEndCallback();
}
```